# C#: XML validation and multiple DTD, MOD and ENT files

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dtd, dita

I'm working on a C# application that validates XML files. So far I've managed to implement single DTD or XSD validation, as well as check for well-formedness.

**CURRENT VALIDATION CODE**

```
// get the path for current XML that should be validated
string xmlPath = listView.Items[currentItemIndex].SubItems[Form1.index_fileName].Text;

// set up the XML reader settings
XmlReaderSettings config = new XmlReaderSettings();
config.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
config.DtdProcessing |= DtdProcessing.Parse;
config.ValidationEventHandler += Config_ValidationEventHandler;

Console.WriteLine("[{1}] Validating {0}", xmlPath, currentItemIndex.ToString());

// setup the XML reader itself
XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, config);

try
{
    while (!xml.EOF)
    {
        // go through each XML node
        xml.Read();
    };
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // and finally report if there's something wrong
    Console.WriteLine("!!! " + e.Message);
    FileDetails.allFiles[currentItemIndex].errorList.Add(e.Message);
}
```

Now I have a problem when it comes to validation of DITA files, as they come with multiple DTD/MOD/ENT files that reference each other. So when I use aforementioned code to validate example DITA file, I get multiple errors:

```
Element 'concept' is not declared.
Element 'title' is not declared.
Element 'conbody' is not declared.
Element 'p' is not declared.
```

All DTD files are accessible, so I believe the problem is that only 1 DTD file can be handled at once and it's not possible to load other ENT/MOD files referenced in the DTD. Here's the part of example DTD that references external files:

**DTD REFERENCES**

```
<!ENTITY % ui-d-dec     PUBLIC 
"-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA User Interface Domain//EN" 
"uiDomain.ent"                                                       >
%ui-d-dec;

<!ENTITY % hi-d-dec     PUBLIC 
"-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Highlight Domain//EN" 
"highlightDomain.ent"                                                >
%hi-d-dec;

<!ENTITY % pr-d-dec     PUBLIC 
"-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Programming Domain//EN" 
"programmingDomain.ent"                                              >
%pr-d-dec;

<!ENTITY % sw-d-dec     PUBLIC 
"-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Software Domain//EN" 
"softwareDomain.ent"                                                 >
%sw-d-dec;

<!ENTITY % ut-d-dec     PUBLIC 
"-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Utilities Domain//EN" 
"utilitiesDomain.ent"
```

Does anyone know how to make use of all these files for validation?

Comment: You will need to use namespaces in each of your DTD file and then use these namespaces to refer in other files.

Comment: DITA-OT or many other product uses Xerces for its DITA validation. But Microsoft architecture based CMS uses MSXML or .net parser. So it is surely possible to validate DITA topic using them. But Microsoft parser does not use catalog file. How do you specify system identifier in target XML file? Or what supplied DTD file are you using?

Comment: @R Jain, thanks, but do you know a way that wouldn't require modification of DTD files? I'm not creating them, all DTDs come with XML files and can be different for each XML files set, so I'd like to have a parser that automatically resolves all external references in DTD files.

Comment: @tmakita I'm playing with these DITA files and their DTDs:
http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/dita.html

Comment: @Marcin Murawski, Unfortunately there is no DTD file found in both src and bin distribution. The most reliable DITA DTD files that work with Microsoft architecture CMS is here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dita-ot/files/DITA-OT%20Stable%20Release/DITA%20Open%20Toolkit%201.8/  DITA-OT1.8.5_full_easy_install_bin.zip

Comment: @tmakita, thanks. The problem appears with these DTD files as well so it's fine to reference them instead.

Comment: Maybe you should implement the latest DITA DTDs, that can be found here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/dita-v1.3-part3-all-inclusive.html

Comment: @xephon thanks but I've checked multiple DTD file sets - all of them are fine, it's just their design what I'm struggling with (I'm unable to resolve their external references using C#)